# Gitlab runner unable to run aws commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run GitLab's job using their shared Runners,
I've created a `.gitlab-ci.yml` and kept it at my project's root,
Configured AWS creds as the environment variables -

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

under `Settings -> CI / CD -> Variables`
[image]

Double checked the branch I've trying to build from is `protected`

**Following is my .gitlab-ci.yml -**

```
stages:
    - build

build:
    image: python:latest
    stage: build
    script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install -y zip unzip
            - pip install awscli
            - mkdir ~/.aws/
            - touch ~/.aws/credentials
            - pip install awscli
            - printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\nregion = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" >> ~/.aws/credentials
            - bash cicdScript.sh
```

**CICD script has the aws command -**

```
$(aws s3 ls)
```

**But I still get the following error -**

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

**Reference -**
https://medium.com/faun/continuous-static-upload-to-aws-s3-using-gitlab-runners-17f0260a5af2

Comment: It's as the error says, it can't find the `aws` command. Which `image` are you using for this? Can you post your `.gitlab-ci.yml` ?

Comment: seems like you just don't have AWS command line tools installed on your GitLab host

Comment: @Rekovni Added the .gitlab-ci.yml and env variable setup

Comment: Uncertain why you're using `[eb-cli]` in the `credentials` file, maybe try using `[default]` instead? Although it's unsecure, what happens when you try `cat ~/.aws/credentials` after the `printf`? (do revoke your keys after this though if it does work...)

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
- pip install awscli
- aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- aws configure set region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

instead of

```
- mkdir ~/.aws/
- touch ~/.aws/credentials
- pip install awscli
- printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\nregion = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" >> ~/.aws/credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the profile is set to 'eb-cli' for your credentials

```
printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\nregion = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" >> ~/.aws/credentials
```

The command you should use is

```
aws s3 ls --profile eb-cli
```

If you dont pass the profile, [default] will be picked. Since default was not configured the issue is caused.